# Countif / Count Formula required

Tags: excel

Got a weird formula that I'm trying to work out.

What I want to do is as follows:

```
If Any of the following cells A1 , B4 , D9 etc have a value then +1
The do the same again for another range of cells.
```

This will need to repeat up to 8 cell ranges

Then I want to get the count of how many times it has had to +1

So for example if 1 cell in each range have values, I want it to +2 etc but if none of the specified cells have values then do nothing.

All the above needs to tagged onto the end of an existing formula that does the following.

```
=X1/Count(Cell Range)*Z1
```

What I need is that, when it gets the value for Z1, if the above cells mention earlier, it needs to add that +2 for example to Z1

Sorry for the long winded description, I can't think of a better way to explain it.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like you have the blueprint ready - did you try simple going through it procedurally?

Comment: "=CountA(range)" will give you the count if it has value, repeat the same for required ranges then do sum as like you require

Answer (score 0):

This is just to get you started.  To test if any of a group of cells has a value, you cant use *=COUNTA()* or:

```
=IF(A1 & B4 & D9<>"",1,"")
```